# pyspark module not available from within python instance that spark is using

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am using an EMR that I myself did not setup in AWS.

I am trying to understand what Python interpreter spark is using and in my .bashrc I have the following setup `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/mnt/anaconda/bin/python`

When I run our spark-submit command I have used sys.executable to print to the path to the python interpreter and this is indeed the interpreter that its using.

However, when I go specifically to that folder, launch that instance of Python with `./python` and then try `import pyspark` I get:

```
>>> import pyspark
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyspark
```

What's going on here?  Shouldn't this interpreter have the pyspark module installed?

Comment: What is your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

Comment: @JohnGordon `:/mnt/anaconda/bin`

Comment: It seems unlikely that python modules would be installed in a `bin` directory, so that may be your problem.  How/where is `PYTHONPATH` being set?

Comment: @JohnGordon And actually you may be right.  When I print `PYTHONPATH` from within the pyspark code it looks like the `spark-submit ` command is adding more directories to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

Answer (score 0):

When you call spark-submit it will add it's own python folder and the py4j library to PYTHONPATH for you.  They live in the folder spark is installed to, they are not directly installed into the site-packages of the python you are using.  For example, if I pyspark an print out the python path:

```
$ pyspark
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
17/10/17 15:34:04 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/10/17 15:34:04 WARN Utils: Your hostname, rwidmaier resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.4.248.126 instead (on interface em1)
17/10/17 15:34:04 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
/home/rwidmaier/apps/spark/python/pyspark/context.py:195: UserWarning: Support for Python 2.6 is deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0
  warnings.warn("Support for Python 2.6 is deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0")
17/10/17 15:34:09 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
17/10/17 15:34:09 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
17/10/17 15:34:09 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/

Using Python version 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016 15:13:37)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(sys.path)
['',
 u'/tmp/spark-0a08efa7-714a-498b-b5e9-bba48684d52d/userFiles-52012e25-d7af-4599-a214-9637141ed4ec',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/deluge-1.3.11-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/home/ryan/apps/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip',
 '/home/ryan/apps/spark/python',
 '/usr/lib64/python26.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/webkit-1.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

You can see in the list that it has manually added:

- /home/ryan/apps/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
- /home/ryan/apps/spark/python

To ensure that the interpreter is always setup with the right libraries, you just need to set PYSPARK_PYTHON to point to the python install you would like to use, and then run "pyspark" instead of running python directly.  Or alternatively you can use spark-submit if you have want to provide a driver.